# Socket IO with React and Express Error: "WebSocket connection to '.......' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I am just learning socket IO and am trying to build the simplest chat application possible with create-react-app in the frontend and express in the backend.

After I set everything up and run both front and back at the same time, this error displays itself an infinite number of times in my browser: [image: browser errors]

I'm setting my frontend's proxy to my backend port. Would that be the problem?

Here is all my code, starting with the backend:

backend/index.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('server listening on 4000');
});
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log(message);
    io.emit('message', `${message}`);
  });
});
```

frontend/App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const socket = io('/');
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('message', (data) => {
      setMessages([...messages, data]);
    });
  }, [messages, socket]);

  const sendHandler = () => {
    socket.emit(message);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {messages.map((message) => (
        <ul>{message}</ul>
      ))}
      <input
        type="text"
        name="message"
        placeholder="message"
        value={message}
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={sendHandler}>send</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

frontend/package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:4000",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^3.0.5",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you have exactly the same socket.io version on both client and server.  Socket.io is very picky about this.  Versions must match exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Store the socket client reference with [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). This way you never loose the initial reference:

```
const socketRef = useRef(io('/'));
const socket = socketRef.current;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are creating the `io()` connection on every single render of your App, which can happen quite frequently. You need to create that connection only once outside `App()`.